# Getting mouse position in a scrolling canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm creating a Javascript RPG on html5 canvas but I have trouble getting the proper mouse position because of the scrolling. This is how I handled the scolling in the draw function:

```
GOBLINS.View.prototype.draw = function(objects) {

    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    function clamp(value, min, max){
        if(value < min) return min;
        else if(value > max) return max;
        return value;
    };

    var camX = clamp(-objects[1].xpos + canvas.width/2, -100, 250 - canvas.width);
    var camY = clamp(-objects[1].ypos + canvas.height/2, -50, 135 - canvas.height);

    ctx.translate( camX, camY ); 

    ctx.drawImage(dungeon,0,0,365,216,0,0,365,216);
```

I need the mouse position to let the player shoot bullets Nuclear Throne style. If the mouse X is larger than the player X position the player is facing to the right and vice versa. But the more the player walks to the right the more offset the mouse position gets because of the clamping. Can someone please help me?

Comment: shouldn't it be just the mouse pos relative to the window (0 = far left) + scroll offset - character position?

Comment: So you are not talking about a real scrolling like your canvas element is nested in a smaller container right? Then it's quite unclear what you ask. There is no mention of any mouse position in your code. Could you provide a mockup or a live example of the problem please?

Comment: The mouse position code is simply: if(mouseX > player.xpos){
            player.facing = 'right';

Comment: But because of the clamping the X positions aren't recorded properly